# Using an inherited list of objects

Tags: delphi, inheritance

I'm trying to create an object structure where one object contains a list of other objects. I have a base class for both of these, similar to `TCollection`/`TCollectionItem` but a very custom implementation.

```
type
  TMyItemBase = class;
  TMyListBase = class;

  TMyItemBaseClass = class of TMyItemBase;

  TMyItemBase = class(TObject)
  private
    FOwner: TMyListBase;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TMyListBase);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Owner: TMyListBase read FOwner;
  end;

  TMyListBase = class(TMyObjectBase)
  private
    FItems: TList;
    FItemClass: TMyItemBaseClass;
    function New: TMyItemBase;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyItemBase;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TMyMainObject; const ItemClass: TMyItemBaseClass);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Count: Integer;
    procedure Clear;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TMyItemBase read GetItem; default;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyItemBase }

constructor TMyItemBase.Create(AOwner: TMyListBase);
begin
  FOwner:= AOwner;
end;

destructor TMyItemBase.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;


{ TMyListBase }

constructor TMyListBase.Create(AOwner: TMyMainObject; const ItemClass: TMyItemBaseClass);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FItems:= TList.Create;
  FItemClass:= ItemClass;
end;

destructor TMyListBase.Destroy;
begin
  Clear;
  FItems.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyListBase.Clear;
begin
  while FItems.Count > 0 do begin
    TMyItemBase(FItems[0]).Free;
    FItems.Delete(0);
  end;
end;

function TMyListBase.Count: Integer;
begin
  Result:= FItems.Count;
end;

function TMyListBase.GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyItemBase;
begin
  Result:= TMyItemBase(FItems[Index]);
end;

function TMyListBase.New: TMyItemBase;
begin
  Result:= FItemClass.Create(Self);
  FItems.Add(Result);
end;
```

(Pseudo code, sorry if there are any typos)

Problem is, when a new item is created (via `TMyListBase.New`), the object is successfully created, but the inheritance and all its fields are not (The inherited object's constructor is never even called)...

```
type
  TMyItem = class;
  TMyItems = class;

  TMyItem = class(TMyItemBase)
  private
    //various unrelated fields
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    //various unrelated properties
  end;

  TMyItems = class(TMyListBase)
  private
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyItem;
    function New: TMyItem;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TMyMainObject);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TMyItem read GetItem; default;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyItem }

constructor TMyItem.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  //Initialize some fields
end;

destructor TMyItem.Destroy;
begin
  //Destroy some fields
  inherited;
end;

{ TMyItems }

constructor TMyItems.Create(AOwner: TMyMainObject);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner, TMyItem);

end;

destructor TMyItems.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

function TMyItems.GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyItem;
begin
  Result:= TMyItem(inherited Channels[Index]);
end;

function TMyItems.New: TMyItem;
begin
  Result:= TMyItem(inherited New);
end;
```

It appears to be something wrong with the `New` function, but I cannot figure it out. Even though I'm creating the item as its intended item class, it gets further treated as if it were the base class, and none of the inherited members are accessible (giving access violations) because the inherited constructor is never called.

What am I overlooking / doing wrong here?

Comment: can you add virtual to your constructors - particularly if you're using metaclass

Comment: I cannot imagine why you are not using generics

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because there's a whole lot more going on behind the scenes which wasn't necessary or relevant to include. `TCollection` doesn't use generics :-)

Comment: You need to be using generics here. It's crazy to spurn that. TCollection was designed for Delphi 1. Of course it doesn't use generics. You can get rid of lots of your code with generics. You still need virtual constructor. You do need to read Nick's new book and also consider the Spring containers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If there's a way to add other proprietary properties and functions inside the `TList<>` then it just might work but they had nothing to do with my issue so I didn't include them in my question.

Comment: You should, 100% be using generic containers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just to explain more about this, I'm building an API structure where internally the component populates these lists, but the end-use of these objects are not permitted to assign, add, delete, etc. The objects in the list are strictly read-only, and the list objects themselves have other functions/properties specific to them. I appreciate your recommendation, but it doesn't fit well with what I'm actually doing.

Comment: Plus I'm building this to be compatible with every version of Delphi (You know me, I have to keep that wide compatibility range).

Comment: If you could restrict to compilers that have generics, then generics would fit. That you cannot see that means you don't fully appreciate generics. I can help you understand that if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `TMyItemBase.Create()` constructor needs to be declared as `virtual`, and then descendant classes need to `override` it.  This is important when constructing objects using metaclass types.  For example:

```
type
  TMyItemBase = class(TObject)
  ...
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TMyListBase); virtual;
    ...
  end;

constructor TMyItemBase.Create(AOwner: TMyListBase);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FOwner := AOwner;
end;
```

```
type
  TMyItem = class(TMyItemBase)
  ...
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TMyListBase); override;
    ...
  end;

constructor TMyItem.Create(AOwner: TMyListBase);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: When creating instances using a metaclass, you cannot change the arguments of the constructor. Derived constructors **must** `override` the base constructor.

Comment: Got it now, after stepping away from the computer for a while and coming back with a fresh mind :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use generics!

```
    type
      TMyItem = class
        //Implement your class here
      end;

    //Use it now!
    var
      MyItemsList:TObjectList<TMyItem>;

   // or implement your generic class customization:
    type
      TVeryMyItemsList = class(TObjectList<TMyItem>)

      end;
   // Or implement your generic class
   type
     TMyGeneric<T> = class(TObjectList<T>)

     end;
   //where T is any type
```